# New Facebook app requires App Review for Pages API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to set up a new Facebook App that is used to pull in the latest post from a public page into another website. I successfully did this a few months ago, but since the GDPR law has come into effect, Facebook's process of creating new apps has become much stricter, requiring them to go through App Review before allowing access to the Pages API product.

However to go through the App Review process, I need to provide step by step instructions and a screencast of the app in action. This isn't an app in the traditional sense, and how am I meant to show the app in action when I can't get it working without it being reviewed!?

The docs mention that "*While testing and before submitting for review, your app may only access content that is available on a Page that you, as an app admin, developer, or tester, administer. If the app wants to access public content on other Pages, you must submit this feature for review*" - does this mean that I do not to go through App Review if the Developer Account has access to administer the page in question?

Comment: i am not sure if facebook even wants you to be able to pull posts from a page you do not own and present it on your own website. as page owner, i would not want anyone to do this without my permission either, to be honest. just saying. not sure how you would present that in a screencast either.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, if your app will only be loading data from pages that you admin, you don't need review/approval to use that API

That said, if you're making this app to fetch posts from someone else's page it will need approval, and if it's a simple background script i'm not sure how you can have it reviewed - the process is focussed on page management tools used by multiple users rather than once-off scripts

Comment: On 1 aug 2018, Facebook revoked my app access to page data that I administer. Did that happen with anyone else? There is no UI for my app. It is only built to manage that 1 page. Where to go from here?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/